# jQuery Divider Scrollbar Auto-Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering how I would go about making my div's scrollbar for the overflow-y automatically position itsself at the bottom of the div rather than the top.

I've honestly got no clue what to do, not sure if it works in CSS but here is how I setup the overflow.

Code:

```
#chatResults {
    width:510px;
    height:275px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Let me know if you don't understand and you need me to explain it differently!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the scrollbar position with `scrollTop()` and move it to the bottom by passing its `scrollHeight` value.

```
$('#chatResults').scrollTop($('#chatResults')[0].scrollHeight);
```

See this [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NN73W/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have a trick which you can you

You can have an any element at some where around the bottom of div

```
<body onload='scrolldiv()'>  //calling a javascript function for adjusting the position
    <div id='chatResults' >
        .
        .
        .
        <span id='get_to_bottom'></span>  //Some where near bottom  
    </div>
</div>
```

Paste the below javascript code in the head

```
<script type='text/javascript'>       
    function scrolldiv(){
        window.location.href='#get_to_bottom';
    }
</script>
```